# over lap avatar image over background image and element

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I am trying to center overlap my avatar over a background image and maintain how the avatar is centered over the background in a responsive way:

[image]

**Code**

```
<v-card>
    <v-img
        src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg"
        height="200px"
        class="woo"
    >
    <v-avatar style="postion:absolute; left: 44%; top: 80% " rounded width="80px" class="pa-1" height="80px">
        <img width="80" height="80" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg">
    </v-avatar>
    </v-img>
</v-card>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/WNGQrGo?editors=1000)

What's happening is that the avatar over flows the background image, but the avatar gets hidden behind the div. I've tried `z-index` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `overflow` to `visible` of the parent element since it has a fixed `height` of 200px

```
<v-card>
    <v-img
        src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg"
        height="200px"
        class="woo" style="overflow: visible"
    >
    <v-avatar style="postion:absolute; left: 44%; top: 80% " rounded width="80px" class="pa-1" height="80px">
        <img width="80" height="80" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg">
    </v-avatar>
    </v-img>
</v-card>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers